# API to access a user's download history in Google Play?

Tags: android, python, django

for a website I am making in Django, I need to see what apps a user has downloaded in the past.  I know I can federated login through Django and the OpenID to have users login through their google accounts. However, is there any API out there that can allow me to see what android applications this user has downloaded in the past? This would include names, versions, etc. of all android applications the user has downloaded to their account in the past, in addition to what type of phone/device the applications were donwloaded to. I looked at the Google Play APIs on their site and it didn't seem like there was anything that allowed for it. Please let me know if you have any advice or if there is anything that you know of that could help me!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not possible, as the history of google play only belongs to that particular app.
App to app communication is not possible to take data, unless using a content provider.

As every app is treated as a seperate user by the linux kernel.

Comment: I think my post may have been a little ambiguous. I am talking about making a website to access the download history of a particular user. I know I can use OpenID to authorize my users with their Google accounts, but I'm wondering if there is some kind of API that allows me to view the android apps these users have downloaded

Comment: I am not aware of any API like that as I am a novice.